# any way to test for $x<z$ for $\lfloor \frac{p}{x}\rfloor \; \text{mod} \; p$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Assume prime p and z, $z^2<p$.

Given an integer j, how can I test whether j fits certain divisions of p?  For instance, I do not want j to be $\lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor mod\ p$,  $\lfloor \frac{p}{3} \rfloor mod\ p$, and so on, up to $\lfloor \frac{p}{x} \rfloor mod\ p$ for $x<z$.

How can I test for this?   As a subset of acceptable values, I could settle for a test that shows $j \equiv \lfloor \frac{p}{nz} \rfloor mod\ p$ for $n<p/z$.

I have reasoned that for $\lfloor \frac{p}{nz} \rfloor mod\ p$, that the following relationship holds using the definition of the floor function:

$jnz\ mod\ p \equiv\ -(p\ mod\ nz)\ mod\ p$

but am not sure if this helps.

Comment: If $z > p^{1/2}$ is large then you can replace $\{ \lfloor p/x \rfloor, x \le z\}$ by  $\{ \lfloor p/x \rfloor, x \le p^{1/2}\} \cup \{ y \in ( \lfloor p/z \rfloor, \lfloor p^{1/2}\rfloor)\}$

Comment: Making a change.  As it happens, $p>z^2$.